# Ubuntu 19.04 freezes after login with new ram stick

Tags: freeze, ram, 19.04

I was using Ubuntu 19.04 in one of my old machines. It has a 2GB of Ram. I decided to upgrade the RAM so I did insert a new 4GB RAM instead of the 2GB one. Now the system freezes after the login. Just after I enter the password it freezes and not responding but surprisingly it works perfectly with the older RAM. I am a newbie in Ubuntu. Don't know how to solve it. Please help.

Comment: From the grub menu select memtest. It sounds like the new ram is bad.